# Detect difference between key combination and single key

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I detect the difference between a single <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> key combination?

Currently I have the following:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keycode === 17){
        alert('crtl only')
    }
    else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 49) {
        alert('crtl + 1');
      }
 }
```

Comment: `else if` without `if`? Please create a working snippet.

Comment: You use the `ctrlKey`, `shiftKey` etc properties - as you already are, although you appear to have a syntax issue as there's an `else if` with no opening statement

Comment: Have you noticed that hitting Ctrl by itself does absolutely nothing in any application? It's that way for a reason.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol im working on a mac.. so this is no problem

Comment: @gurvinder372 check new snippet

Comment: You need to create a working snippet using `<>` on the toolbar. It will help us in replicating the issue.

Comment: @SiemPeters I have attached an answer with a demo.

Answer (score 0):

When the key(s) are hit, make a note of the time. Then compare it with the time you noted the last time they key(s) were hit.

If the difference is within your threshold, consider it a double. Otherwise, don't.

If the difference is within your threshold, consider it a double. Otherwise, don't.

**Rough example:**

```
 var delta = 500;
    var lastKeypressTime = 0;
    function KeyHandler(event)
    {
       if ( event.ctrlKey 
         && String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).toUpperCase()) == 'T' )
       {
          var thisKeypressTime = new Date();
          if ( thisKeypressTime - lastKeypressTime <= delta )
          {
            doDoubleKeypress();
            // optional - if we'd rather not detect a triple-press
            // as a second double-press, reset the timestamp
            thisKeypressTime = 0;
          }
          lastKeypressTime = thisKeypressTime;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 49){
            alert('combo hit!');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `debounce` with `keydown`

```
function KeyPress(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
  debouce(function(evtobj) {
    if (evtobj.keyCode == 65 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
      console.log("Ctrl+a");
      evtobj.preventDefault();
    } else if (evtobj.ctrlKey) {
      console.log("Only ctrl");
    }
  }, evtobj, 200);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function KeyPress(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
  debouce(function(evtobj) {
    if (evtobj.keyCode == 65 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
      console.log("Ctrl+a");
      evtobj.preventDefault();
    } else if (evtobj.ctrlKey) {
      console.log("Only ctrl");
    }
  }, evtobj, 200);
}

function debouce(method, eventObj, debounceTime) {
  if (this.timeoutId)
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  this.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    method(eventObj);
  }, debounceTime);
}
document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```